# Failed to import the required Python library (botocore or boto3)

Tags: ansible, boto3

I'm running a playbook on localhost, and I've already installed ansible and the required packaged like boto3. The playbook works fine when it is performing tasks on a remote host, but outputs the following error when running locally.

Command:

```
ansible-playbook app.yaml
```

Error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (botocore or boto3) on DESKTOP-9NTDHK1's Python /usr/bin/python3. Please read the module documentation and install it in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter"}
```

Ansible version:

```
ansible 2.10.3
  config file = /home/user/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/user/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/user/ansible/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /home/user/ansible/venv/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) [GCC 9.3.0]
```

Boto3 version:

```
(venv) user@DESKTOP-9NTDHK1:~/ansible$ pip show boto3ersion"
Name: boto3
Version: 1.16.18
Summary: The AWS SDK for Python
Home-page: https://github.com/boto/boto3
Author: Amazon Web Services
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: Apache License 2.0
Location: /home/user/ansible/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: s3transfer, botocore, jmespath
Required-by:
```

app.yaml

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    user: *****
    AWS_PREFIX: *****
    
  tasks:
    
    # provision AWS
    
    - name: Provision VPC
      ec2_vpc_net:
        cidr_block: *****
        region: *****
        name: *****
        state: present
      register: vpc_data
```

Comment: Please read carefully the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/ec2_vpc_net_module.html) => `The below requirements are needed on the host that executes this module.` You are showing us the lib is installed on your controller, it must be installed on your target, even if it is localhost, i.e. the python version used for the 'remote' wihch might be different from the one used by the controller. As advised by the error message, check the doc on ansible_python_interpreter

Comment: @Zeitounator the target host here is localhost, and as specified above,  has all the requirements satisfied. nothing is being executed on a remote host.

Comment: You are executing ansible in a virtualenv. This is not the same environment used when you connect to your target (being localhost). You are using an other environment/version of python where the lib is not installed. Simply install it with the pip module in your playbook to check for yourself.

Comment: It makes sense now. i am indeed using a virtual env. so now is there any way to set the interpreter to use the venv instead of the one outside of it (localhost) ?

Comment: `ansible_python_interpreter: /path/to/your/venv/bin/python`. Please read the docs as advised by your error message and myself in my first comment.

Answer (score 3):

I was running ansible in a docker container where python and pip is also installed.
Running the below command solved my problem.

`pip install boto3`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extract of a playbook:
note the vars section.
ansible is not aware of the venv in which it is launched.

```
- hosts: all
  connection: local
  become_user: tim
  vars: #local connection defaults to using the system python
    ansible_python_interpreter: /home/tim/pycharm_projects/django_api_sync/ansible/venv/bin/python3
  vars_files:
    - includes/secret_variables.yml

  tasks:
    - name: create a DigitalOcean Droplet
      community.digitalocean.digital_ocean_droplet:
        state: present
        name: "{{droplet_name}}"
        oauth_token: "{{digital_ocean_token}}"
        size: "s-2vcpu-2gb"
        region: SGP1
        monitoring: yes
        unique_name: yes
        image: ubuntu-20-04-x64
        wait_timeout: 500
        ssh_keys: [ "{{digital_ocean_ssh_fingerprint}}"]
      register: my_droplet

    - name: Print IP address
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: Droplet IP address is {{ my_droplet.data.ip_address }}
```